# Is there another way to store Folder Path in EXCEL VBA than using Sheets?

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel VBA project that uses ADODB and manipulates data in an ACCDB.

I know that you can store the path for the ACCDB in a cell of the excel sheet. However I would like to know: Is there another way to store the path rather than in the sheet?

I know that if I store it in a variable, when the program closes it releases the variable.

If you ask me why I want this, it's more because I want the code not being too dependent in the front-end of the excel, as some unskilled people will also use this project.

Perhaps there is a more professional or known way to store folder or file paths?

Comment: Open Name Manager and create one with that path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store it in a Custom Document Property.

Or in a Name using the Name Manager.

Or in a cell of a hidden Worksheet.

Comment: Or a custom xml part